# Automatically launching an Android app after building and installing on a device

Tags: android, gradle, adb

During development, I would like my app to launch immediately after installation on a device.

For example, after completing installation with

```
$ ./gradlew installDebug
```

I would like the app to launch on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Paste your own variant of the following code into your app's `build.gradle` file.

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.install != null) {
        variant.install.doLast {
            launchApplicationActivity("com.myapp.MyActivity", variant.getApplicationId())
        }
    }
}

def launchApplicationActivity(activity, applicationId) {
    try {
        ("adb shell am start " + applicationId + "/" + activity).execute()
    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        print 'Failed to start application. (Make sure adb is on your path).'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not Gradle related but works. You can create a BroadCastReceiver and receive the system Intent that flags your app installation. The implementation would be something like that:

In your manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="yourpackage.Receiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And your receiver:

```
public class EquipeOnReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
    {
        //yourcode
    }
}
```